# Mutual Exclusion in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I have written a program in python that handles two threads. One thread is plotting from an array the other is appending data to the arrays the other thread is plotting. Since both threads are accessing the same arrays I had decided to use a condition variable to ensure mutual exclusion when accessing said array. However I forgot to implement it.

I was at the same time interested in the execution time for different parts of the code. Therefore I used the function time.time() to establish execution time. When I removed the parts measuring the execution time the function no longer worked.

This made me realize that I had forgotten to implement the condition variable. I did and it worked. I am however confused as to why the program worked without the CV when I measured the time? Was it just that the added execution time of the second thread made it less likely for both the threads to access the array at the same time?

In the code below I have commented the use of the CV out.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from threading import Thread, Condition
import time
import random
import sys

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
condition = Condition()
xs = []
ys = []
i = 0
running = 1
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def getData():
    return random.randrange(1, 10, 1)

def animate(i):
    #condition.acquire()
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
    #condition.release()

def terminate():
    global running
    print("Goodbye")
    running = 0
    sys.exit()

class sensorHandler(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while(running):
            startTime = time.time()
            global i
            number = getData()
            #condition.acquire()
            if i<10:
                i = i+1
                xs.append(float(i))
                ys.append(float(number))
            else:
                ys[:] = ys[1:]
                ys.append(float(number))
            #condition.release()
            print(time.time()-startTime)


if __name__=="__main__":
    sensorHandler().start()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100)
    plt.show()
    terminate()´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know for certain because it is quite difficult to verify<sup>1</sup>, but I expect that removing `time.time()` exposed a time-dependent synchronization failure which would not show up with the added expense of executing `time.time()`.

So I believe it is as you say, "*the added execution time the second thread*" lowering the likelihood of conflicting access - a statistical mutual exclusion of sorts. Of course proper implementation of the conditional variable forcibly ensures synchronization.

The multithreading scheme here is safe (when the CV is properly implemented) because all matplotlib actions are performed in a single thread, but it should be noted that [matplotlib is not thread safe](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/faq/howto_faq.html#working-with-threads) and if matplotlib actions are to be split across multiple threads then the access to the artists must be properly serialized.

---

<sup>1</sup> Potential verification methods tend to be destructive - if the computational expense of executing `time.time` is sufficient to hide the issue most normal debugging methods will also.

Comment: Thank you for the repsonse! Yes I assumed matplotlib not being thread safe. I did also rewrite the code so that the function plotting the array copied the arrays then plotting the copy. This allowed for a shorter CV locking section.